# Static files couldnt applied in Django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm new in Django and i see course in youtube
I try to include bootstrap\css files into HTML template and i created a static file into the app like the photo 
Also i checked the file(second\ urls.py) and in it the code

```
'''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
'''
```

And in login.html there is this link

```
''' 
 {% load static%}
  <link rel="=stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accounts/style.css' %}">
'''
```

I applied other way like adding this second\setting.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"accounts/static"),
    'accounts/static/'
]
```

And this is my urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [   
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In the terminal there is warning but i think it isnt affect

```
WARNINGS:
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^account/' has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an
 oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().
```

[image]

Comment: can you show your urls.py file

Comment: 'from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings

from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: After looking in your application code, I've found the problem.

You have to put this code

```
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in the main `urls.py` file , in your case is the `second/urls.py` .

And make sure you have this code

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'name_of_the_root_directory/static'),
]
```

in your `settings.py` file

---

Have you run the `collectstatic` command ? `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Maybe try changing this in your `urls.py` file

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Into this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is my configuration in `settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'name_of_the_root_directory/static'),
]
```

And this is my `urls.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [   
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

If you follow my example, you have to run the `collectstatic` command from the terminal window

Comment: Do you have a git repo with your application ? So I can see your code better

Comment: I've made a new pull request to your repository on github, with the static files fixed. I hope it will help you. You have made the wrong changes to your code. You've put the static setting in the wrong urls.py file. You have to put it in the main urls.py, in your case second/urls.py . I will edit my post